# Printer Option "Print" and "Cancel" want to make in dark text

Tags: ios, printing

I want to show Printer options "Print" and  "cancel" buttons darker. it is not visible. Please help, How I can get dark text.

[Example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZjK6.png)

Comment: Just set the tint color to `[UIColor black]`

Comment: tint color of....can you explain...I tried tint color of navigation bar but its not working

Comment: Please share the code snippet.